# Are all JWT payload keys considered claims

Tags: jwt

[The standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2) uses the word `claim` a lot and defines it as:

> Claim
>
> A piece of information asserted about a subject.  A claim is
> represented as a name/value pair consisting of a Claim Name and a
> Claim Value.

So is my understanding correct that in the following payload:

```
{
    "iss": "joe",
    "exp": 1300819380,
    "http://example.com/is_root": true
}
```

all three keys `iss`, `exp` and `http://example.com/is_root` **are claims** with the difference that `iss` and `exp` are [registered claims](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) and `http://example.com/is_root` is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following quote from the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) (highlight is mine):

> [**3.  JSON Web Token (JWT) Overview**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3)
>
> JWTs represent a set of claims as a JSON object that is encoded in a
> JWS and/or JWE structure.  This JSON object is the JWT Claims Set.
> As per [Section 4 of RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4), the JSON object consists of
> zero or more name/value pairs (or members), where the names are
> strings and the values are arbitrary JSON values.  **These members are
> the claims represented by the JWT.** [...]

Both [`iss`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.1) and [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) are [registered claims](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) while `http://example.com/is_root` is also a claim, but it's not registered in the IANA [JSON Web Token Claims registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml).

---

In summary, the keys of the payload are called *claims*.